# torch.nn.Sequential of designed blocks problem in giving inputs

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, sequential

I have designed a class that is a block of a network and its forward has three inputs: x, logdet, reverse, and has two outputs.
for example, everything is normal when I call this class and use it, like:

```
x = torch.Tensor(np.random.rand(2, 48, 8, 8))
net = Block(inp = 48, oup = 48, mid_channels=48, ksize=3, stride=1, group = 3)
a, _ = net(x, reverse = False)
```

But when I want to use it by Sequential(because I need multi blocks after each other), the problem occurs like this:

```
x = torch.Tensor(np.random.rand(2, 48, 8, 8))
conv1_network = nn.Sequential(
    Block(inp = 48, oup = 48, mid_channels=48, ksize=3, stride=1, group = 3)
        )
conv1_network(x, reverse = False)
```

My error is:
`TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reverse'`
And it is not normal because I have reverse in my inputs of forward in Block as we see in the first part.
I'm looking forward to finding a way to attach some Blocks to each other for example this is a block

```
class Block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_channels):
        super(InvConv, self).__init__()
        self.num_channels = num_channels

        # Initialize with a random orthogonal matrix
        w_init = np.random.randn(num_channels, num_channels)
        w_init = np.linalg.qr(w_init)[0].astype(np.float32)
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.from_numpy(w_init))

    def forward(self, x, logdet, reverse=False):
        ldj = torch.slogdet(self.weight)[1] * x.size(2) * x.size(3)

        if reverse:
            weight = torch.inverse(self.weight.double()).float()
            logdet = logdet - ldj
        else:
            weight = self.weight
            logdet = logdet + ldj

        weight = weight.view(self.num_channels, self.num_channels, 1, 1)
        z = F.conv2d(x, weight)

        return z, logdet
```

And my purpose is to attach multi Blocks to each other in Sequential in a for(because I can't use the same Block in my work, I need different convolutions for making a deep network)

```
features = []
for i in range(10):
   self.features.append(Block(num_channels = 48))
```

and then I want to use them like this

```
self.features(x, logdet = 0, reverse = False)
```

Comment: what version of pytorch are you using. It should be okay for later versions.

Comment: My Pytorch version is 1.9.0+cu111, so it seems it doesn't relate to the version right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicated that your `Block` `nn.Module` had a `reverse` option. However nn.Sequential doesn't, so `conv1_network(x, reverse=False)` is not valid because `conv1_network` is not a `Block`.

By default, you can't pass `kwargs` to layers inside a `nn.Sequential`. You can however inherit from `nn.Sequential` and do it yourself. Something like:

```
class BlockSequence(nn.Sequential):
    def forward(self, input, **kwargs):
        for module in self:
            options = kwargs if isinstance(module, Block) else {}
            input = module(input, **options)
        return input
```

This way, you can create a sequence containing `Block`s (and optionally non-`Block` modules as well):

```
>>> blocks = []
>>> for i in range(10):
...     self.blocks.append(Block(num_channels=48))

>>> blocks = BlockSequence(*blocks)
```

Then you will be able to call `blocks` with the `reverse` keyword argument, which be relayed to every potential `Block` child module when called:

```
>>> blocks(x, logdet=0, reverse=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, but what can I do for making sequential of many Block nn.Module?Because when my Block forward path has just one input everything was fine

Comment: If `conv1_network` is a `nn.Sequential`, then you can inverse the sequence of layers it contains with a slice: `conv1_network[::-1]`.

Comment: But my main problem is how to make sequential containing of Blocks, can I do this? It was possible for me when forward in my Block class had just one input:x but when I added another input I cant make sequential by this Block anymore

Comment: Can you elaborate on this and show a minimal example by editing your question?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I edited and added an example.

Comment: @Nikoo_Ebrahimi I have edited my answer, see above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238974/discussion-between-nikoo-ebrahimi-and-ivan).

Comment: Apologies, it should be `blocks = BlockSequence(*blocks)` since `blocks` is a *list*.